# Excel copy/paste on same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a macro that will copy the last column of data, paste that value over itself and then paste the formula into the next empty column.

I have tried this

```
Sub copyformula() 
    Range("N3").End(xlToLeft).Copy 
    Range("N3").End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work, as I said I am new and learning as I go.

Comment: I' am new, I have tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments.  Just update your answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Range("N3").End(xlToLeft).Copy
Range("N3").End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

You can learn a lot by using the Macro recorder and examining the resulting code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub user()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set r2 = r.Columns(r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1)
    r2.Copy r2.Offset(0, 1)
    r2.Copy
    r2.PasteSpecial (xlValues)
End Sub
```